# Android AES Decryption takes time

Tags: android, performance, encryption, cryptography, aes

I have done research and tried to find solution but I feel I am helpless. 
I have app which is constantly running (music app, which runs 24x7) and in case if there is restart needed app does automatically. Our tracks are encrypted and before playing we decrypt. But what I found that after restart for the first time decryption takes way too much time. Sometimes 5 minutes, 10 minutes, 18 minutes. Not sure what is happening, this happens on 2 devices out of 6 with Android 5 OS. Can anyone please help me here?

Here is my code snippet.

```
File f1 = new File(inputFile);
if (f1.exists()) {
  CommanFunction.writeErrorLogInFile(MyApplication.getmContext(), 
    "LodingMusic Call Start --> doCrypto() " + f1.getAbsolutePath());
  inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
  outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
  byte[] iv = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
  IvParameterSpec ivParams = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
  Key secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), ALGORITHM);
  Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
  cipher.init(cipherMode, secretKey, ivParams);
  CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(inputStream, cipher);
  int b;
  byte[] d = new byte[131072];
  while ((b = cis.read(d)) != -1) {
    outputStream.write(d, 0, b);
  }
  outputStream.flush();
  outputStream.close();
  cis.close();
  CommanFunction.writeErrorLogInFile(MyApplication.getmContext(), 
    "LodingMusic Call End --> doCrypto() " + f1.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

**UPDATE**

Ok, I have done further investigation, this code takes time:

```
while ((b = cis.read(d)) != -1) {
        outputStream.write(d, 0, b);
      }
```

Can anyone please help me in this?

Comment: Are you decrypting all the files en masse or on demand?

Comment: It's on demand and only one file at a time.

Comment: Is it really decryption taking the time of maybe just file io? What if you just copy files after restart?

Comment: ok but if it's file IO problem then how can we resolve it? I'll check for copy operation.

Comment: @algrid you are right, it's file write operation takes time, can you please help in this?